# remove href from link using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code to remove the href links from my page. It works great except I do not want to target all the links. Instead, I want to target all of the links within a div, like disable all the links of a particular div with an id "test2".

```
var all_links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i=0; i<all_links.length; i++){
    all_links[i].removeAttribute("href");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for that. Pass a [CSS selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) that matches the elements you need to target. From what you have described, `div#test2 a` will do:

```
var all_links = document.querySelectorAll("div#test2 a");

for(var i=0; i<all_links.length; i++){
    all_links[i].removeAttribute("href");
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/w62asaLf/1/)

Or, for maximum compatibility (IE <9):

```
var all_links = document.getElementById('test2').getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options for this, here using ES6:

```
// retrieving all <a> elements within <div id="test2">, using
// document.querySelectorAll() and converting that collection
// into an Array, using Array.from():
var all_links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#test2 a"))

    // iterating over that Array using Array.prototype.forEach(),
    // along with an Arrow function to remove the 'href' attribute
    // from each of the <a> elements in the Array:
    .forEach(link => link.removeAttribute('href'));
```

```js
var all_links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#test2 a")).forEach(link => link.removeAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<a href="#href1">Link 1</a>
<div id="test2">
  <a href="#href2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#href3">Link 3</a>
</div>
<a href="#href4">Link 4</a>
<div id="test3">
  <a href="#href5">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#href6">Link 6</a>
</div>
```

Or, rather than removing the `href` attribute setting it instead to the value of `'#'`:

```
var all_links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#test2 a"))

    // here we use setAttribute() to set the value of the href
    // attribute to the '#' value:
    .forEach(link => link.setAttribute('href', '#'));
```

```js
var all_links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#test2 a")).forEach(link => link.setAttribute('href', '#'));
```

```html
<a href="#href1">Link 1</a>
<div id="test2">
  <a href="#href2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#href3">Link 3</a>
</div>
<a href="#href4">Link 4</a>
<div id="test3">
  <a href="#href5">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#href6">Link 6</a>
</div>
```

Or, given that an `<a>` element without an `href` attribute arguably serves no particular 'purpose' we could instead unwrap the text, or other contents, and remove the no-longer-useful `<a>` element:

```
var all_links = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll("div#test2 a") )

  // using the anonymous function of Array.prototype.forEach() rather
  // than Arrow functions, given the work being done here:
  .forEach(function(link){

    // while the <a> element has a firstChild:
    while(link.firstChild) {

      // we access the parentNode of the <a> and
      // use the insertBefore() method to insert
      // the firstChild of the <a> before the <a>:
      link.parentNode.insertBefore(link.firstChild, link);
    }

    // once the <a> is emptied of its content,
    // we again access the parentNode and remove
    // the <a> element itself:
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
});
```

```js
var all_links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#test2 a")).forEach(function(link) {
  while (link.firstChild) {
    link.parentNode.insertBefore(link.firstChild, link);
  }
  link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
});
```

```html
<a href="#href1">Link 1</a>
<div id="test2">
  <a href="#href2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#href3">Link 3</a>
</div>
<a href="#href4">Link 4</a>
<div id="test3">
  <a href="#href5">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#href6">Link 6</a>
</div>
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
- [`while (...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Answer (score 1):

As the jQuery tag is included:-

```js
$('#test2 a').removeAttr('href');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="test">test</a> 

<div id="test2">
  <a href="test1">test</a>
  <a href="test2">test</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this with jQuery you can use the following:

```
$("div#test2 a").removeAttr("href");
```